# Calling WDF driver from c++

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, wdf

I've been trying to call a sample driver. I have written DriverEntry method, where I initialize both the driver name and symbolic ling pointing to the driver.

```cpp
// UNICODE_STRING DriverName, SymbolName; // Driver registry paths
...
    // Driver Entrypoint
    NTSTATUS
    DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath) {
  Q_UNUSED(pRegistryPath);

  DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Driver Loaded\n");

  // The PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine routine registers a driver-supplied
  // callback that is subsequently notified whenever
  // an image is loaded (or mapped into memory).
  PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine(ImageLoadCallback);

  // initialize driver name
  RtlInitUnicodeString(&DriverName, L"\\Device\\Explorer");
  // initialize symbolic link
  RtlInitUnicodeString(&SymbolName, L"\\DosDevices\\Explorer");

  IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, 0, &SymbolName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
                 FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &pDeviceObject);
  IoCreateSymbolicLink(&DriverName, &SymbolName);

  pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = CreateCall;
  pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = CloseCall;
  pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = IoControl;
  pDriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadDriver;

  pDeviceObject->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;
  pDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I load the driver up (using OSR Driver Loader, could be done using cmd also, by registering the driver as a new service), I get expected output in DebugView (sysinternals tool allowing to see kernel debug logs)

[image]

Now I needed to make sure that both the device and symlink are present in Windows Object Directories. To do that, I use WinObj (another tool from sysinternals), here is the output

What confuses me here, is that the symbolic link is in **Device** folder, instead of **GLOBAL??**. 
Symbolic link in Device
[image]

Device in GLOBAL??

[image]

Now, finally, calling the driver itself. I use c++ for that purpose and this is my code,

```
class Test
{
public:
HANDLE hDriver; // Handle to driver

                // Initializer
Test::Test(LPCSTR RegistryPath)
{
    LPCSTR path = "\\\\.\\Explorer";
    hDriver = CreateFileA(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);


    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //  Handle the error.
        char result = GetLastError();
        bool zadek = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't get a valid handle for the driver. The value of hDriver is always either 0x00000000000000a0 or 0xffffffff, no matter the path I use. I'm using createFileA because I want to access system memory.

Is there some blatant mistake I made?

Comment: value of 0x00000000000000a0 is a valid handle value for `hDriver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should say it is over 8-9 year since last time I written a device driver, but what comes off the top of my head are:

1. You say you get `0xa0` for `hDriver` which is a valid handle value.
2. Right now, you can only use device IO control, because you only have callback for `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL`.
3. Try `L"\\??\\Explorer"` or `L"\\GLOBAL??\\Explorer"` for symbolic link.
4. You need to use `DriverName` for `IoCreateDevice`.
5. You are passing incorrect arguments to `IoCreateSymbolicLink`.

So your code should become like this:

```
...
// initialize driver name
RtlInitUnicodeString(&DriverName, L"\\Device\\Explorer");
// initialize symbolic link
RtlInitUnicodeString(&SymbolName, L"\\??\\Explorer");

IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, 0, &DriverName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
                 FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &pDeviceObject);
IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymbolName, &DriverName);
...
```